# Need a function to create a smaller hash from a larger hash

Tags: algorithm, hash

Basically I have 24 digit hexadecimal id values. I need a function that can take one of these ids and turn it into a 10 digit decimal value. It does not need to be cryptographically secure. I just need to ensure that the same input will always get the same output, and that the resulting value has as low of a chance as possible to be the same with different inputs.

Comment: Without knowing something about the distribution of those hexadecimal ID values, we can't suggest anything with a lower chance of duplicates than just converting from hex to decimal and taking the last ten digits.

Comment: See also: [smaller hash from a standard hash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32913069/3789665).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work as you are asking -

```
shorterHash := MD5(hexId) # 16 byte
return shortedHash.substring(0, 10) # this is still non-colliding enough
```

I hope there are many standard implementations of MD5 on your language on internet.

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept the answer if it's working.

Comment: I will, can't for 5 more minutes.

Comment: ... which is 10 bytes and thus by far greater than 10 decimal digits.

Comment: Do you have any idea to store a digit in less than 1 byte?